# How can I route internet connection from isolated interface with iproute2?

Tags: linux, networking, iproute

I am trying to create a dhcp server with `iproute2` and the DHCP part is working fine, yet the clients don't get any internet.

The host is getting internet from 192.168.150.0/25 network and functions as a router/DHCP-server for the subnet 192.168.169.0/24.

The clients will get the ip's from the correct ip address range, when I connect them to the same interface as the host machine.

This is my network config.

```bsh
# Starting interfaces
ip link set dev eth0 up 
ip link set dev eth1 up

# Assigning addresses to interface 
ip addr add "192.168.150.29/25" dev eth0 brd +
ip addr add "192.168.169.1/24" dev eth1 brd +

# Specifying how eth0 will get his internet.
ip route add default dev eth0 via "192.168.150.1" scope global
```

**My question is how can I route the internet connection from eth0 to eth1 as well.**

I was trying to add the route like this:

```bsh
ip route add "192.168.169.1/24" dev eht0
```

and similar but it says `wrong prefix` when I have `"192.168.169.1"` if I change `1` to `0` then I get another error that `File exists` or `Nexthop has invalid gateway.`

Thank you in advance

Also as a note:
I don't know if it is important, but both eth0 and eth1 is bridged into the machine which is running on libvirt.

Comment: ponder https://xyproblem.info/ and please explain in plain words *what* you are trying to achieve, not *how* (because it's not working). Giving an example involving "clients", router (and maybe router's router) and Internet would help. Also where is DHCP involved if anywhere?

Comment: Thanks, Now I have made my situation/environment and question more clear.

The machine itself is functioning as a DHCP server, for anyone who connects to the interface eth1.

Should I include my DHCP configuration files as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `ip route add default via 192.168.169.1 dev eht0` on clients or push the route through DHCP server (depends on which one do you use, you don't specify that in your question). Also make sure you have ip_forwarding enabled (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` = 1) and make sure you have masquarading (NAT) enabled via iptables/nftables. Alternatively if you control the machine with IP 192.168.150.29, you can add there `ip route add 192.168.169.0/24 via 192.168.150.29` and avoid masquarading.

Comment: Thank you. I have access to all the computers, and 192.168.150.29 is the same computer that I am doing the configuration on. When I try `ip route add 192.168.169.0/24 via 192.168.150.29` I get error File exists, and if I try ip route it says that the route for `192.168.169.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.169.1`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I forgot to disable the default firewall and network manager on my system so I was running `SuSeFirewall2` and `wicked` in the background which was messing up with my settings.

my final network setup ended up like this

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
start)
        echo "Starting the network"


        echo "search my.dns.server.ext" > /etc/resolv.conf
        echo "nameserver 192.168.150.1" >> /etc/resolv.conf

        ip addr add "192.168.150.29/25" dev eth0 brd +
        ip addr add "192.168.169.1/24" dev eth1 brd +
        ip link set dev eth0 up
        ip link set dev eth1 up
        ip route add default via 192.168.150.1 scope global

        echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

        ;;
stop)
        echo "Stopping the network"
        ip addr flush eth0
        ip addr flush eth1
        ip link set dev eth0 down 
        ip link set dev eth1 down 
        ;;
restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
*)
        echo "Usage $0 [start|stop|restart]"
esac
```

I also had to manually setup DNS in `/etc/resolv.conf` after disabeling wicked, but now it works as a charm.

:-)